# ¿Cómo puedo deserializar un json complejo en una lista dinámica usando c# y .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, jsonobject

Necesito deserializar un json en una lista dinámica ya que no puedo usar modelos para deserializar, porque mi json es distinto. Lo necesito deserializar para después pasarlo a un excel en array de bytes.

La primera complejidad que se me presenta es el json, ya que puede tener más listas dentro del json.

Despues de pasar el json a una lista, mi complejidad es leerla ya que hay listas dentro de listas, para recuperar todos los valores como cabeceras del fichero excel y luego ir leyendo las filas para ir construyendo el fichero excel

El json como ejemplo, para que se vea que dentro hay más listas se este:

```
  [
   {"AplicacionId":10,
   "Nombre":"App1",
   "AplicacionesDescripcion": [
        {"AplicacionesDescripcionId":1,"Descripcion":"prueba1"},
        {"AplicacionesDescripcionId":3081,"Descripcion":"prueba2"}]},
    {"AplicacionId":11,
    "Nombre":"App11",
    "AplicacionesDescripcion": [
            {"AplicacionesDescripcionId":2,"Descripcion":"prueba33"},
            {"AplicacionesDescripcionId":44,"Descripcion":"prueba34"}]}
]
```

¿Alguna idea?
He leído que la librería NewtonSoft.Json ofrece muchas posibilidades, intenté deserializar el json en la siguiente lista:

```
var resposneJson1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, 
object>>>(parametroJson);
```

Pero ahora tengo que tratar las columnas y filas para poder pasarlo a un fichero excel usando EPPLUS y no soy capaz de ver como puedo leer la lista cuando tengo varios niveles de listas.

Comment: Puedes copiar el JSON y luego, "Pegado especial -> como clase", luego usa esa clase para Deserializar

Comment: No, no puedo usar clases, ya que puedo recibir json con estructuras distintas

Comment: Quizás esto te pueda ser de ayuda: https://makolyte.com/csharp-deserialize-json-to-dynamic-object/